# Publishing Azure Mobile Service with Custom Login Provider (.NET Backed)

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, azure, azure-mobile-services

I've been trying to add a way for people to login to my universal windows app and have succeeded in allowing them to login through Microsoft, Google, Twitter, and Facebook (just because these are supported directly by Azure), but I can't seem to correctly set up a custom login provider.

I tried following [this tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/). It works locally, but once it is published to azure it fails.

Here is the first line from the log: Exception=System.NotSupportedException: There is no store type corresponding to the conceptual side type 'SByte' of primitive type 'SByte'.

I'm assuming the problem lies with how the control stores the users:

```
todoContext context = new todoContext();
context.Users.Add(newUser);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Does this save it to a local database or something instead of the database on azure. If so, how would I have it store the User to the azure database?

Edit:
On second though I think I have found the problem. After trying it again and connecting the local mobile service to my azure database I got this error:

{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"There is no store type corresponding to the conceptual side type 'SByte' of primitive type 'SByte'.","exceptionType":"System.NotSupportedException","stackTrace":"

I'm now assuming that it is unable to create a table corresponding to my User class:

```
public class User : EntityData
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public byte[] Salt { get; set; }
        public byte[] SaltedAndHashedPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Although, I don't know why it's trying to create a table when I already have a table... Is there a setting I have to change?

Otherwise...

How would I be able to store the Salt and SaltedAndHashedPassword on my database? Would I have to convert them to strings and then convert them back again somehow? Is that even possible?

Also, why would it be able to create the table for User locally and not on azure?

Edit:

There must just be something wrong with my mobile service because when I tried to use the tables api to get the todoItems that it came installed with it, it returned the same error I provided above.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this only works when you are taking a code first approach to the Mobile Service.

I fixed it by creating a new mobile service and connecting it to a new database. I then created a new Mobile Service Project through the download link the mobile service gives you on the portal. I then created all the models I needed as classes, updated the DataContext, and created all the controllers.

Even though I've gotten it to work I would still like to figure out how to do this with a database first approach.

Comment: Model First is supported, but not trivial. If you have an existing model, see this tutorial on how to add the right system properties and map to data transfer objects: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-use-existing-sql-database/